# What is the best way to force an Application Start when an Application Pool is recycled?

Tags: .net, application-pool, application-start, recycle

I'm wondering if there is a way to automagically fire off an Application Start for a web site/application whenever the Application Pool for that site is recycled?

Are there any canned solutions for this problem?

I would really like to avoid having one of my end users have to go through the application start of the site if they can avoid it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are using .NET 4 you can.

```
<applicationPools>
     <add name="MyAppWorkerProcess" managedRuntimeVersion="v4.0" startMode="AlwaysRunning" />
</applicationPools>
```

See more information at ScottGu's article [Auto-Start ASP.NET Applications](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2009/09/15/auto-start-asp-net-applications-vs-2010-and-net-4-0-series.aspx).

Other than this I have heard of people writing a service to make a request every few minutes. A little overkill, imo, but depends on your need.

Comment: Awesome, I totally didn't know that existed.

Comment: This requires IIS 7.5 or above right?
I cannot get it to work in IIS 7... help?
EDIT: Nvm it works in IIS 7.

Comment: @MartinClemensBloch I'm trying to get this working in IIS 7, but i get an error that "startMode" is not recognized. Did you have todo anything else to get it working?

Comment: @Cadab I dont remember if I fixed something else, restarted the IIS or just tried again. But it should definitely work in IIS 7. Btw there might be a slight delay between setting that setting and the worker thread starting.